# In Javascript ES6 How to change each element in an array to an object with key value pairs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, ecmascript-6

So I have an array

```
const audioList = ["song1", "song2", "song3", "song3"];
```

I want to convert it into where every element has been turned into an object with a key-value pair of played : false added.

```
const newaudioList = [{audio : "song1", played : false}, {audio : "song2", played : false}, {audio : "song3", played : false}]
```

I also want to do this with JavaScript ES6 with something like forEach. Has anyone got any ideas? Thank you

Comment: What's so special about ES6? Why not ES2016 through ES2021?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the [map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

The map method will iterate over an array and create a new item for each element in the array. In the callback that you pass to it, you can do your transformation from a string to an object as follows.

```js
const audioList = ["song1", "song2", "song3", "song3"];

/*
  This is one way to accomplish this in one line. It is pretty easy to read and understand. The outer () is a little weird, but necessary so JavaScript will see the inside of it as a new object and not a 'closure'.
*/
const newAudioList1 = audioList.map(item => ({ audio: item, played: false }));
console.log(newAudioList1);

/*
   This is another way to accomplish the above and might seem a little too verbose, but this approach can be helpful for debugging purposes. The stack trace will have this method name, whereas above, it will only show an anonymous function and might be harder to track down the source of the error.
*/
function transformToObject(s) {
    return { audio: s, played: false };
}
const newAudioList2 = audioList.map(transformToObject);
console.log(newAudioList2);

// const newaudioList = [{audio : "song1", played : false}, {audio : "song2", played : false}, {audio : "song3", played : false}];
```

Comment: This is the most comprehensive and has taught me new ways of thinking about it. Thank you for the time in making it so clear and informative.

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over the array using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). In each iteration, return an object with the current `audio` element and `played:false`:

```js
const audioList = ["song1", "song2", "song3", "song3"];

const res = audioList.map(audio => ({ audio, played: false }));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This is what I did but without the brackets. Thank you.

Comment: @woisme this is by far the simplest solution and probably what I would use in production personally. You can always use something like `song => ({ audio: song })` but `audio => ({ audio })` is much more concise and leaves the lengthier property declarations for new properties like your `played` property. Great solution, Majed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you explicitly mentioned **forEach** usage.

Here you go.

```
const audioList = ["song1", "song2", "song3", "song3"];
var newaudioList = [];
audioList.forEach((e) => {
    newaudioList.push({
        audio: e,
        played: false
    })
});
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you for your time in responding. I got myself in the end in all sorts of a mess with new Class which always feels just wrong.